# SQL Join with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, join, pgadmin, postgresql-13

I need a query to fill the column `netto` from table `test` with values from `lv` from table `co` when two conditions `(test.sp= co.sp) AND (test.ver= co.ver)` are given

Table test:

| sp | ver | netto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | Null |
| B | Y | Null |
| C | Z | Null |

Table co:

| sp | ver | lv |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | F |
| B | Y | G |
| C | Z | H |

I've tried this query, but it doesn't work.

```
UPDATE test
SET test.netto= co.lv
FROM test
JOIN co ON (test.sp= co.sp) AND (test.ver= co.ver);
```

Result should be (table test):

| sp | ver | netto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | F |
| B | Y | G |
| C | Z | H |

I get the following error message:

```
Error : ERROR: table name specified more than once
```

Comment: What is the dbms? Is this greenplum/postgres?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please read the edit help re block formats for code & quotes & re table format (but that's not appropriate for when a table is initialization code).

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via a [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including in Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: "What is the dbms" "cut & paste & runnable code & example input" table format (but that's not appropriate for when a table is initialization code" "research" etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update statement was close.

```
update test
   set netto = co.lv
  from co
 where test.sp = co.sp
   and test.ver = co.ver
```

Output of select * from test:

```
A   X   F
B   Y   G
C   Z
```

Where test and co were set up as:

```
create table test (
  sp varchar(10), 
  ver varchar(10), 
  netto varchar(10)
  );

insert into test values 
('A','X',''),
('B','Y',''),
('C','Z','');


create table co (
  sp varchar(10), 
  ver varchar(10), 
  lv varchar(10)
  );

insert into co values 
('A','X','F'),
('B','Y','G'),
('K','Z','H);
```